# Managing Path for access database

Tags: c#, .net, database, ms-access, path

I have a C# project which uses a database and currently the database is not embedded in the exe or C# project. I use the following path:

```
connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Anant\Documents\WebsiteSearch.accdb;
                                            Persist Security Info=False;";
```

Is there any way I can just add the WebsiteSearch.accdb into the project and change the path accordingly. The idea is when someone starts the exe on some other computer I don't want always to change the path of the database.

Answer (score 2):

For this usually we put the database in the application folder itself. If you put the db in the `bin/debug` than it would be always easy to access the DB

your code will turn like this

```
connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
Data Source=WebsiteSearch.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;";
```

Or alternatively,

```
connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
Data Source="+AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"WebsiteSearch.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `|DataDirectory|`:

```
connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\WebsiteSearch.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;";
```

`|DataDirectory|` is a substitution string that eliminates the need to hard-code the full path to the datebase.

You can then call `AppDomain.SetData` to set its value at runtime, if you don't, it will default to the application's folder, so the easiest option would be to include your database in the same folder as your application executable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use relative path

```
ConnectionString = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\WebsiteSearch.accdb";
```

or in your c# code

```
  string executable = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    string path = (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(executable));
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", path);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the solution explorer mark the `accdb` file as 'Content' and set it as 'Copy if Newer'.

This will make sure the DB is always there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are recompiling every time then you can also put your connection string in app.config file, and deploy it to your machines. Whenever you want to change the connection string you can simply edit config file, no need to recompile code every time.