# How to connect the database file even though the path has changed?

Tags: c#, database, path, connection-string, oledb

I'm working on a student database the problem I have is when I'm working on the project on another computer and the path of the database changes I have to write the connect code again for the new Path, I've tried a lot of ways non of them worked here is the code.

```
    public partial class LoginFrm : Form
{
    OleDbConnection Mycon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\Projects\Programing\StudentInfo\DataBase\StudentDB.mdb");
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Not necessarily the best idea for security reasons, but have you considered putting the path in the “app.config” file? Then read this path in your code from the app.config file. Then you can change the path in the `app.config` file and you do not have to recompile the code.

Comment: You will find potential answers to your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370938/managing-path-for-access-database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Managing Path for access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370938/managing-path-for-access-database)

Comment: @JohnG sorry I didn't really get what you mean I have tried adding the path in the app. config but I still have to change the path in-app.config code if the database file path change. the only way that worked if the 

Data Source = StudentDB.mdb in this case it will look for the database file in the "bin\Debug" so I have to copy the database file to that path

Comment: Sorry, I am not following, in this example, let’s say when the app starts, it looks to see if there is an entry in the app.config file… let’s call it “DataPath” and its value would be the whole path you have in your code. If there is no entry, then you can either ask the user to supply it using a pop-up window to enter the path OR simply set a “default” path and write this to the app.config file. Then read the path back and use it. If the “DataPath” already exist, then the code will use it. If the path fails when the app loads… then you should be able to change this in the app.config file.

Comment: You have two choices, “change” the app.config `DataPath` entry by manually editing the app.config file using a text editor… OR … create a small form that allows the user to enter the new path then update the app.config file to the new path. I would guess allowing the user or you to change the path would be a better approach using a small window to enter the path. Sorry if I am missing something.